# Format decimal property to currency inside class

Tags: c#

I have created a class

```
public class XYZ: DomainObject
{   
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Commission { get; set; }
}
```

Now I use `Price` property in many place . I get a requirement to change my price value `5454` to `5,454.00` .

So I use this one

```
@String.Format("{0:N}", Model.Price)
```

But in this approach I have to do above thing at so many places I want to do something with my `Price` property inside my class . So that when ever a person try to get this property . He gets the formatted value `5,454.00` .

What should I do ?

Comment: Just create a new read-only property.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici Why don't you give a complete answer with example .

Comment: MarcinJuraszek was already working on it :)

Comment: code the format in the ToString() method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your property is a `decimal`, so it has no format assigned to it. You can add another property of `string` and hide the format there:

```
public class XYZ: DomainObject
{   
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public string PriceString
    {
        get { return Price.ToString("N"); }
    }

    public decimal Commission { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: is this work on all places where i have used `Price` , I mean to say does this solution set formatted value in `Price` ?

Comment: No, because as I wrote, `decimal` has no format specified at all. It's just a value.

Comment: Hmmm , this mean that i have to change `Price` to `PriceString` every where . Am i right ?

Answer (score 0):

Well what about something like this:

```
public string PriceFormatted { get { return string.Format("{0:N}", Price); } }
```